# C# Report RDLC, Informe Media Carta

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer, rdlc, informes

Tengo un reporte en tamaño media carta Horizontal pero a la hora de imprimir sale de forma vertical:

**Necesito que salga de esta manera:**

[image: Sale de esta manera]

**Pero sale:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leído opciones como que el tamaño de la Hoja sea más alta y que deje la parte inferior vacía, y funciona, pero para mi caso no, ya que el informe contiene una tabla de tamaño dinámico el cual hace que el informe sea en más de 1 hoja, por lo que al renderizar quedan objetos fuera de la hoja.

Así esta configurado el reporte:

```
<PageHeight>5.5in</PageHeight>
<PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
<InteractiveHeight>20cm</InteractiveHeight>
<InteractiveWidth>20cm</InteractiveWidth>
<LeftMargin>0.19685in</LeftMargin>
<RightMargin>0.19685in</RightMargin>
<TopMargin>0.19685in</TopMargin>
<BottomMargin>0.19685in</BottomMargin>
<ColumnSpacing>0.05118in</ColumnSpacing>
```

La impresora de igual manera está configurada en 8.5 * 5.5 Horizontal.

Aclaro compañeros, ya he realizado todas las investigaciones, configurado la impresora horizontal y vertical, he gastado como una resma de papel, he renderizado en imagen, la he girado 90 grados son muchos los cambios que he probado pero no logro que salga de forma correcta. El reporte ya generado lo he exportado a PDF desde el visor y al imprimirlo sale bien, pero desde el ReportViewer o imprimiendo directamente no sale correcto.

Les agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que 
algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el 
[Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio 
y en [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AntonioGalicia muchas gracias, en este caso mi consulta no es propiamente de código, sino de una salida del mismo, entiendo lo de la imagen pero creo que es la forma mas sencilla ejemplificar mi post

Comment: Creo que no estás entendiendo, `mi consulta no es propiamente de código` , si no es código, entonces, ¿cómo vas a realizar algún cambio al momento de realizar la impresión? Antes que te agarren a negativos y/o te cierren la pregunta, te invito a leer estas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos. PD: Por si no quedó claro, sí tiene que ver con código.

Comment: @fredyfx muchas gracias por su comentario, lo voy a tomar en cuenta

Comment: Para servirles hermano :D y bueno, como no hay código, te doy una pista para investigar: tiene que ver con "portrait" y "landscape".

Comment: Esto está muy cerca de lo que deseas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267191/3613462

Comment: Hola Andres podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util y en caso de serlo marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

En las propiedades de tu reporte selecciona la **opción Landscape**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma las dimensiones de tu reporte se invertirán haciendo que **el ancho sea ahora el alto y viceversa**, no descarto que debas además de hacer esto modificar otras características de tu reporte, quizá quitar el **header** o el **pie de página**, ajustar los márgenes a la izquierda, derecha, arriba y abajo, pero esas pruebas van por ti.